# Array in android set value

Tags: java, android, asp.net, arrays, web-services

why in this array android in debug not pass value 2 (value of item "Other") when is selected value is "Other" ?
In debug I've "Other" string ...
thank you for any help.

```
 <string-array name="nation_arrays">
    <item>Pick one</item>
    <item value="1">Usa</item>
    <item value="0">Mex</item>
    <item value="2">Other</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Android doesn't support attribute for XML string & array resource.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this problem like this:

Create two arrays in array.xml

```
<string-array name="nation_arrays_name">
    <item>Usa</item>
    <item>Mex</item>
    <item>Other</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="nation_arrays_value">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>0</item>
    <item>2</item>
</string-array>
```

Now in your code create two arrays to hold values:

```
String names [] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.natoin_arrays_name);
String values [] =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.natoin_arrays_value);
```

To get value from another array you can use:

```
values[Arrays.asList(names).indexOf(names[i])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two different arrays: one for descriptions, one for values.

```
<string-array name="language_entries">
    <item>@string/lang_default</item>
    <item>@string/lang_eng</item>
    <item>@string/lang_ita</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="language_values">
    <item></item>
    <item>eng</item>
    <item>ita</item>
</string-array>
```

Access arrays in this way:

```
String[] langDesc = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.language_entries);
String[] langISOs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.language_values);
```

Comment: thank you for help, but in this code I've exception ...Request.addProperty("nation", nation.getResources().
                   getStringArray(R.array.nation_array_values));
        
        
        <string-array name="nation_arrays_name">
            <item>Usa</item>
            <item>Mex</item>
            <item>Other</item>
        </string-array>
        <string-array name="nation_arrays_value">
            <item>1</item>
            <item>0</item>
            <item>2</item>
        </string-array>

Comment: What kind of exceptions? What is Request? Please, be more specific.

Comment: the message is: Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application

in this line: Request.addProperty("nation", nation.getResources(). getStringArray(R.array.nation_array_values));

Comment: What you wrote is not enough to let me understand. Please, copy and paste here the whole message appearing in the Markers or Problems view.